# Как при переворачивании экрана писать предупреждение?

Tags: html, css

суть
пользователь открыл сайт на планшете в горизонтальной версии
открыл вертикальную - выводится текст ( переверните экран, чтобы просматривать сайт)

Comment: почитайте статью http://nikitakiselev.ru/article/otslezhivanie-izmeneniya-orientacii-na-mobilnyh-ustroystvah-s-pomoshchyu-javascript

Answer (score 2):

Добавляем в структуру HTML документа блок с сообщением о том, что пользователь неправильно держит устройство. Обычно в него ещё добавляется контейнер-обёртка для текста, а сам блок растягивается на весь экран при помощи:

```
position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
```

По-умолчанию скрываем этот блок при помощи `display: none;` А при помощи media-запросов показываем, когда ориентация отлична от ожидаемой.

HTML:

```
<div class="warning-orientation">
    Переверните устройство
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.warning-orientaion {
    display: none;
    /* Other styles you need */
}
@media screen and (orientation="landscape") {
    .warning-orientation {
        display: block;
        /* Other styles you need */
    }
}
```